# Electron issue with Mac M1

Tags: reactjs, macos, electron, apple-m1

Bought latest Mac M1.I'm trying to install modules for my project and got an error

```
Response code 404 (Not Found) for https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.4.3/electron-v9.4.3-darwin-arm64.zip
```

Answer (score 6):

New chip M1 is supported only from version 11, you are trying to download version 9

Read this to get more information:

https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-11-0